# Handle Ioctl call while running with qemu

Tags: linux, gdb, qemu

I am using qemu to emulate a binary like this

`qemu -strace XXXXX` .

I saw that the first 2 system calls of this process were `TCGETS` to stdin and stdout. From man pages

```
Get and set terminal attributes
      TCGETS Argument: struct termios *argp
              Equivalent to tcgetattr(fd, argp).
              Get the current serial port settings.
```

And after those 2 syscall the process got `SIGSEGV`.

Is there any simple way to handle those syscall so the process continues without a segfault?